# Need help changing z-index of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, z-index

So, I am doing an assignment for my high school web design class, and I am having trouble getting the z-index of an image to change. There is supposed to be 2 images on top of each other. When you click the button on the page, the image on bottom will come to the top (or the top image will go to the bottom). Here is my code that I`m using:

The javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Switch()
{
document.getElementById("mononoke2").style.zIndex = "-1";
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div id="mononoke2">
<img src="mononoke2.png" alt="ashandsan">
</div>
<div id="mononoke3">
<img src="mononoke3.jpg" alt="sanandmoro" width="1234" height="694">
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="Switch()">Flippity Flip</button>
```

And the CSS

```
#mononoke2 {
margin-left: 0px auto;
margin-right: 0px auto;
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
}
#mononoke3 {
margin-left: 0px auto;
margin-right: 0px auto;
display: block;
position: relative;
left: 50px;
z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle illustrating your problem

Comment: I can, and it works just fine, that is it sets the zIndex as expected -> **http://jsfiddle.net/jg5vH/**

Comment: So we know what you're trying to accomplish. Care to tell us what's happening instead? Or do you just expect us to write your code for you?

Comment: If the different components work as expected in the fiddle, but not in your local HTML document, chances are there's a problem in your document when combining it all together.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery.

```
$("#id").css("zindex","-1");
```

Comment: I agree it's easy with jQuery, but loading a 93 kb library for one simple effect may be somewhat overkill? :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS function to this:

```
function Switch() {
    var element = document.getElementById("mononoke2");
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    var index = style.getPropertyValue("z-index"); 



     if(index > 0)
     {
     document.getElementById("mononoke2").style.zIndex = "-30";
     }
     else
     {
    document.getElementById("mononoke2").style.zIndex = "100";
     }
}
```